# Select statement, need case like functionality in the where statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

I'm on sql 2000.

I am getting all the banners to display on a website.

If the displayedCount != -1, then always get the row.  Otherwise, I need to make sure it isn't larger than the maxViewCount column.

So the table is like:

```
bannerID  viewCount maxViewCount
1         -1         0
2         100        200
3         0          200
4         201        200
```

So I need a select statement that will return bannerID's  1, 2, 3

- 1 is returned because the viewCount is -1 (unlimited)
- 4 isn't returned since it has a viewCount > maxViewCount.

Is this possible with a SELECT statement or it requires a temp table?

Comment: What if viewCount = maxViewCount?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE viewCount = -1 OR maxViewCount > viewCount
```

Comment: When viewCount is greater, it should not return. The second clause in your query is incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT bannerID,
       viewCount,
       maxViewCount
FROM table 
WHERE viewCount = -1
   OR maxViewCount > viewCount
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
where
    maxViewCount >= viewCount
or  viewCount = -1
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED**

```
 SELECT bannerID,viewCount,maxViewCount
 FROM TABLE
 WHERE viewCount = -1 OR viewCount <= maxViewCount
```